# how to do opencv haartraining with opencv from ROS?

Tags: opencv2, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to opencv haartraining and really need some help. I want to train my own haar classifier so I followed some step by step tutorials:

but I am stuck because I can't find the haartraining folder which is needed in --> cp src/mergevec.cpp ~/opencv-2.4.5/apps/haartraining

The problem is I am using opencv installed with ROS hydro (version opencv 2.4.6) and I cannot find where is located the haartraining folder which I need.

I tried using bash comands: sudo find / -iname 'haartraining', sudo find / -iname 'apps', sudo find / -iname 'opencv', sudo find / -iname 'opencv2' but none of these helped me find the haartraining folder.

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.

*Can you suggest how to find the folder haartraining, or how to do the haartraining with opencv from ROS?*

Please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165451/how-to-do-opencv-haartraining-with-opencv-from-ros?/) by [Pollon](https://answers.ros.org/users/18066/pollon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-15**:
it would help if you show what compiler error you get (if using C++)  and your package's Manifest.xml and CMakefiles.txt
How did you install OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have found 'opencv_haartraining' file into 'opt/ros/hydro/bin/' folder on my computer. I am also using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

However, please note, there is new version of haar training program. It is 'opencv_traincascade'. This program also is located into 'opt/ros/hydro/bin/' folder.

You can use this program like the following sample:

```
opencv_traincascade -data haarcascade_file -vec pos_samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -numStages 20 -precalcValBufSize 2000 -precalcIdxBufSize 2000 -featureType LBP -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.05 -numPos 3000 -numNeg 3019 -w 24 -h 24 -mode ALL
```

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pollon](https://answers.ros.org/users/18066/pollon/) on 2014-05-17**:
Thank you :)